# What documentation shows the associated numbers for linux signals like SIGTERM and SIGKILL?

Tags: documentation, signals

I can look around the internet and find that the associated number for SIGKILL is 9, but is there linux documentation (such as, a man page) showing the complete list of signals and their numbers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[man 7 signal](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?signal+7)

Comment: The kill(1) man page should refer to the signal man page in the "SEE ALSO" section

Answer (score 11):

The signal(7) man page (at least the one I have) shows multiple possible numbers for some of the signals.  If you can get `kill` to list the numbers, they should be correct for the running system.  Try:

```
kill -l
```

or

```
kill -L
```

In both cases, that's an "ell" (for "list"), not a "one".  Bash's built-in `kill -l` shows a nice numbered table.  Linux's procps `kill -l` shows a terse list of names without numbers, but `-L` shows a table with the numbers.  BSD `kill` seems to only understand `-l`, and won't show you the numbers.

Comment: The `-L` option is better because it also shows the numbers associated with the signal names, and puts them in a nice table format. My version of procps is **3.2.8**.

Comment: @Tshepang: Thanks!  Answer updated.  I hadn't actually thought to try anything but Bash's built-in `kill`.

Answer (score 2):

Also look in /usr/include/signal.h and either scan the #define or #include statements (which on Ubuntu 10.10 tells you to look in /usr/include/bits/signum.h).  Note that the SIGRTMIN/SIGRTMAX are placeholders for kernal and unused signals and should not be called by the shell or a program.